# D3 Sunburst Breadcrumb on Y Axis

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm new to D3 and am trying to modify Kerryrodden's sequences sunburst with displaying the breadcrumb on the Y (vertical) axis.

Here is an example of what I'm going for:
[image]

Here is a fiddle for where I'm at: http://jsfiddle.net/niceux/tth0goc7/

Basically, i've tried finding where the svg group is being appended, and swapping the x axis code with the y axis code on line 199 of the fiddle code:

```
entering.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", b.w / 2)
      .attr("y", (b.h + b.t) / 2)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Comment: I have tried modifying the existing examples code where the breadcrumb gets initialized and swapping out the X axis code and Y axis code, but can't seem to find anywhere that would flip the axis. 

Even a hint in the right direction would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fiddle with the basics to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/8m2gn7vw/2/

I made a few changes. Firstly, this was the code section determining how each breadcrumb polygon was positioned:

```
// Set position for entering and updating nodes.
g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
});
```

Switching the `translate` to position breadcrumb nodes vertically was a case of fixing the **x-axis** at 0 and calculating the **y-axis** position instead, as well as switching the breadcrumb polygon width (`b.w`) for the height (`b.h`) like this:

```
return "translate(0, " + i * (b.h + b.s) + ")";
```

Next I needed to modify the `<div id="sequence"></div>` html element to fit the new shape of the breadcrumb trail. It was easiest to remove the `sequence` div all together and create a new div with `id=leftsidebar` based on the existing `<div id="sidebar">` element used on the right side for the legend. I modified the CSS to give size and position for the new div.

Finally I moved the `percentageString` into the correct position, below the last breadcrumb node. For this I made a switch to `x` and `y` attributes from:

```
d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
    .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
    .attr("y", b.h / 2)
```

to

```
d3.select("#trail").select("#endlabel")
    .attr("x", b.w / 2)
    .attr("y", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.h + b.s))
```

For further improvements, you'd probably want to re-shape the breadcrumb polygons (they point right at the moment which looks odd